# Dynamically Enable LAN traffic in Firewalld (using profiles in network-manager)

Tags: networking, 14.04, network-manager, firewall

I am trying to use firewalld to allow dynamic profiles for different connections in Network Manager.  When I'm at home, however, I would like to allow anything coming in on the LAN (local subnet).  I can easily set the local subnet in rules, of course, but I really would like to have the local subnet set by the network.  If I am in another trusted network I don't want to have to configure the Local Subnet for that network in the firewall.

Example, in my home LAN my system has a Local Subnet of 10.0.0.1/255.255.255.0 but at my father's house his local subnet is 192.168.0.1/255.255.255.0 and at my friend's house he uses 10.0.1.1/255.255.255.0 and I'd rather not have to configure an explicite firewall zone for each of those.

In Windows it will detect my local subnet and usually automatically makes those rules permissive.  I don't want to do this globally as my work uses the same local subnet as my home network and I don't trust that network beyond a few required services.

Any help would be appreciated.